# Any tools to cross check whether all the magento enterprise code has been removed from the community edition after the downgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, ce-1.9.0.1

I have downgraded one site from magento enterprise to community edition based on the below blogs/forums, after that we have made few changes to the site work perfectly in the community edition. And the site working fine now and it's live with community version.

https://gist.github.com/ProxiBlue/87208724f758d5da472f
http://www.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/

And we have applied for the Certification of Compliance to the magento team to close the enterprise agreement, however we got the reply from the magento team there are still few elements related to enterprise code still in the site and needs to be clean up to close the agreement.

We have cross checked the site very closely but we are unable to find a code/option related to enterprise code, even we have requested to the enterprise team to provide the documents/reports which show the enterprise code still in the site but it seems like they will receive the status as true/false, that's it. They don't have any other details.

And let us know, is there any proper tool or suggestions to cross check and find the enterprise code with the site.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have a copy of enterprise then why not use a diff tool to compare file contents between your community version and the vanilla enterprise version?

Any files that are identical could be an enterprise file. You could then do a comparison between vanilla community magento and your new version for the files that the first diff says is identical - to remove any files that are shared between both.

Comment: Note that the files from CE have different copyright headers in EE. The only real EE files are files that are not present in CE.